# URL redirecting but not with .htaccess?

Tags: url, redirect, url-rewriting, joomla2.5

I have the following problem:

Which method of (non .htaccess) URL redirection can I use to tell google that pages with URL.

Example - `mysite.com/group/12-category/17-article (12 and 17 are category id and article id automatically inserted in url by joomla cms)` 
which have good position on google search results at the moment, are the same with `mysite.com/group/category/article` which are my new urls.

Comment: You edited my question so it is now incomprehensible. Make sentence as it was - >>Which method of (non .htaccess) URL redirection can I use to tell google that pages with URL example mysite.com/group/12-category/17-article (12 and 17 are.....<< There is no point mark behind URL! It is ok to remove words from title that are not allowed but trying to correct grammatical errors and making my question nonesense is not OK!

Comment: Why are you excluding htaccess? That would be the easiest way to do it if you want to do a bunch of URLs.